# Showing $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_T \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}dz=0$ if $T$ is a circle with radius R and $deg(q)\ge deg(p)+2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Showing $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_T \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}dz=0$ if $T$ is a circle with radius R and $deg(q)\ge deg(p)+2$.

I got stuck in this stage, if I take a parameterization $\phi(t)$ I get:
$$\|\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_T \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}dz\|\le\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \|\frac{p(\phi(t))}{q(\phi(t))}\|\|\phi'(t)\|dt$$
now I'm trying to show that $\|\frac{p(\phi(t))}{q(\phi(t))}\|\alpha \frac{1}{R^2}$ which make sense, but, I failed to show that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint, from which you ought to be able to easily finish the problem. Begin by proving the following important lemma:

**Lemma**. If $f$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$, then there exists an $R > 0$ such that

$$|z| \ge R \implies \frac 1 2 \le \frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^n} \le 2.$$

This is just a quantitative version of what you're aiming for.

To prove this, write $f(z) = z^n + a_{n - 1} z^{n - 1} + ... + a_0$ and see what happens when you divide by $z^n$.

Comment: I struggled to show it, here is my try-please tell my if I'm wrong:
$$\frac{f(z) = z^n + a_{n - 1} z^{n - 1} + ... + a_0}{|z|^n} \le 1+ \frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|z|}+...+\frac{|a_{0}|}{|z|^n} \le_{*} \frac{1+n*a_max}{R} \le_{**} 2$$
$$*-a_max=max{|a_{n-1}|,...a_0} \ \ and \ \ |z| \ge R \ge 1$$
$$**-R \ge n*a_{max} \ \ and \ \ R\ge 1$$
So I made more assumptions in order to show it, and I'm not sure about them. $\\$
Moreover, also when using it to show that  $$\|\frac{p(\phi(t))}{q(\phi(t))}\|\alpha \frac{1}{R^2}$$

I made more assumption which is that $|b_nz^n| \ge|b_{n-1}z^{n-1}+..|$ when Z>>1